# How to transfer live WordPress site to Wamp?

Tags: database, wordpress, testing, wamp, wampserver

I've got a wordpress site that I have been using for a year now and it is hosted with HostGator. I have got a few tests i would like to run on the site, but I would like to test it offline using wamp first before making it LIVE.

The problem is previously I was always making changes to the LIVE site, usually at hours when I get little to no traffic. However, that has changed now and I do get traffic most hours through out a 24hr day.

So my problem is:

1. How do i download my existing website to laptop (wamp) and make those changes with new theme? (total newbie, sorry!)
2. I use Windows 7, so not sure what I need to be doing to get the site working like a live site offline.
3. Once I have implemented the new changes, what is the best way to upload the updated site back to the HostGator server without having any downtime or errors for site visitors?

Is there anything else I need to install or do inorder for this to work? I hope you can give me as much information as possible or any links to any guides or articles that explain how to do this.

Thanks so much for any help you can offer!!!

Comment: are you running wamp at the moment? There is actually a plugin called migrate db which you can export the db and import in your wamp version of wp (exact same installation just using localhost as your weburl) I assume you are making changes to a plugin or theme, thats all you need to re-upload to your live site.

Comment: There must be a 1000 blogs out there suggesting ways of doing that. Just search on `wordpress live to local` and pick one. Or use the documentation on the [wordpress site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Hostgator, the process is simple:

1. Install [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/index.html) or [WAMPP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) on your computer;
2. Go to your cPanel, backup and download your website;
3. Extract the backup to your computer, specially the homedir and the sql;
4. Go to your local environment, access `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`
5. Create a new database, doesn't matter the name but for the example let's call it "database";
6. Inside that database, import the one taken from the backup;
7. create a new folder inside your htdocs with the name of your website, "example.com";
8. Extract the content of the homedir there;
9. edit wp-config with the following data:

Host: 'localhost'
Username: 'root'
Password: blank

10. access `http://localhost/example.com`

You can check a good tutorial about the subject [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/).

About putting the site live, I recommend you to use a GIT repository, however it's understandable that might be a little complicated and perhaps too much work for what you're trying to achieve.

Try to move your files directly from your local to live environment using Filezilla or WinSCP, the drag and drop should replace the files live and the downtime should be minimal.

Comment: I followed this so thanks! An additional step was needed, I had to do a find/replace for the live URL within the DB and swap to my new local URL to stop my site from redirecting to the live version. Here's a brilliant tool I found to help with the SQL query https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/full/nzEjI

Comment: Note: In step 7, on XAMPP the folder may be `htdocs`, but in WAMP, the folder may be `www`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of WAMP, you can always use VirtualBox to install CentOS or Ubuntu/Debian.

You can go one further and install either CentminMod to automate creating a LAMP, or a full panel like ISPConfig or Virtualmin.

That take care of create the environment.

Create a new account on the LAMP, using the same domain name.

You can FTP with Windows to get the files, but networking Windows and Linux is a pain. The better option is to use the command line (CLI) in the Linux VM to ftp the files from Hostgator to the VM. This guide will help with that process: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/FTP-3.html

Then your only concern is the MySQL database. And for this, you have several options.

For me, the easiest is to buy (or try!) SQLyog on Windows, and then copy the database from the Hostgator source to the localhost destination. Some mild networking is needed for Windows to see the Linux VM, but nothing as complex as file sharing (the FTP issue). SQLyog is far quicker than backing up the database, then restoring it -- especially since you can run into memory issues doing it this way. It fully depends on the size of the database.

The cheap/free backup>restore method is to use phpMyAdmin.

WordPress also has plugins, of varying cost, but you still have the possible backup>restore memory issue there as well.

When done, just copy it the other way, again using SQLyog and CLI ftp. You'll still have some downtime, but it will hopefully be minimal.

As a newbie, this probably seems like rocket science, but at least it gives you a good place to start. Welcome to the world of locally dev'ing sites!

Comment: If you're going to go with virtualbox you might as well go all in and move your WP to a docker container. Of course that means ditching HostGator but I see that as a good thing.